# Visual Studio Profiler "Calling thread must be STA" PRF0025

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

I'm working on a C# console app that uses several tasks to implement threading.  When I try and profile the program using the Visual Studio 2013 profiler in "Instrumentation" mode, the profiler collects data and writes it as the program runs, but when the run completes, the following error is output:

```
Data written to C:\...\Console140910.vsp.
Profiling finished.
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
PRF0025: No data was collected.
```

Surely you can connect the profiler to multithreaded applications.  Anyone see this problem before? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well, that's certainly not supposed to happen.  The usual place to start when Visual Studio falls over in such bizarre ways is by disabling VS add-ins.

Comment: See, that's the problem.  I'm not running any.